# How to run awk on all the files inside a folder separately then combine the output into one?

Tags: bash, awk, ansible, stdout

This is a type of file inside my folder, there are more files like this inside the folder:

```
#ServerName example.com
ServerName www.site1.com    site3.com
domain.site4   domain65-something.dom    

dasad.sdsd
#ServerName example.f
Databases
#ServerName yeah
```

I ran this command:

```
awk '/^ServerName/ {f=1} f {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/\./) print $i; else if($i!="ServerName") exit}' file
```

and I get this output:

```
www.site1.com
site3.com
domain.site4
domain65-something.dom
dasad.sdsd
```

Which is exactly what I want.

But I want to run this command on all the files inside the folder so I get all the vhosts in the output.

So that it looks something like this:

```
www.site1.com
site3.com
domain.site4
domain65-something.dom
dasad.sdsd
domainform.file2
domain.from.file2
domainfrom.file3
domain.from.file3
```

Keep in mind that this should run as a shell module inside an ansible-playbook.

I tried:

```
cat * | xargs awk '/^ServerName/ {f=1} f {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/\./) print $i; else if($i!="ServerName") exit}'
```

But it does not work. I also tried it without xargs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just wrap your command in loop, use `ls` to get your file names, and the output of this gets saved to the variable `$file`

`ls |while read file; do awk '/^ServerName/ {f=1} f {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/\./) print $i; else if($i!="ServerName") exit}' $file; done;`

Comment: I get a syntax error message in ansible with the offending line in code is here>\ . / after "if ($i~/" but if I copy that exact same command from shell module directly into the server, it works just fine.

Comment: Hmmm, nevermind. I just removed the qoutes in the shell module and it worked.

Comment: Don't use plain `ls` in commands. It's output is not easily predictable and you shouldn't parse it in scripts. Use `find` instead. (or at least add option `-1` to `ls`)

Comment: No, don't parse the output of ls at all, just use `for file in *` if a loop was necessary but you don't need that loop at all.. Also do quote your variables and don't call read without IFS= and -r. See the bash FAQs

Answer (score 1):

In your original script just change `exit` to `f=0` and change `file` to `*`:

```
awk '/^ServerName/ {f=1} f {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/\./) print $i; else if($i!="ServerName") f=0}' *
```

Comment: Now I feel stupid. I should read manual of `awk` before posting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command on each file one by one, in a loop.
Shell will automatically concatenate the output into a single stream at the end of the loop.

```sh
find . -type f \
| while read -r file
do
    awk '/^ServerName/ {f=1} f {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/\./) print $i; else if($i!="ServerName") exit}' $file
done \
| cat #Here you have entire output for all files. You can pass it to further commands or save to a file.
```